# Pointer error queue

Tags: c++, queue

[image]

Hi. I have a string of digits like in the picture above. I want to print them in decreasing order using a minimum number of queues. The input also acts like a queue.

My idea is to take first digit from the right and create a queue. Then for each other digit check if it is bigger than the first digit in any queue. If it is, add it to that queue. If it is not, create a new queue and repeat the procces.

I have written the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Nod{
    int info;
    Nod *urm;
};

void push(Nod *&p, Nod *&u, int info){
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        p = new Nod;
        p->info = info;
        u = p;
        u->urm = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        Nod *q = new Nod;
        q->info = info;
        q->urm = p;
        p = q;
    }
}

void pop(Nod *&p, Nod *&u)
{
    if (p != NULL){
        Nod *q = p;
        if (q->urm != NULL){
            while (q->urm->urm != NULL)
            {
                q = q->urm;
            }
            delete u;
            u = q;
            u->urm = NULL;
        }
        else
            p = NULL;
    }
    else
        cout << "Empty Queue";
}

void print(Nod *p)
{
    cout << endl;
    Nod *q = p;
    while (q != NULL)
    {
        cout << q->info << " ";
        q = q->urm;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Nod *p, *u;
    p = u = NULL;

    Nod *p1[100];
    Nod *u1[100];

    char * s;
    s = new char[100];
    cin >> s;

    push(p1[0], u1[0], s[(unsigned)strlen(s) - 1]-'0');

    for (int i = (unsigned)strlen(s) - 2; i >= 0; i--){
        int k = 0; int ok = 0;
        while (p1[k] != NULL)
        {
            if (s[i]-'0' >= p1[k]->info)
            {
                push(p1[k], u1[k], s[i]-'0');
                ok = 1;
                break;
            }
            k++;
        }
        if (ok == 0)
            push(p1[k], u1[k], s[i]-'0');
    }

    //test printing first 3 lines.
    print(p1[0]);
    print(p1[1]);
    print(p1[2]);
    system("Pause");
}
```

I have a crash at this line which I believe it's caused by a pointer error? I'm using Visual Studio 2013. I've tried using the debugger but still I can't figure out what's the problem. I also wanted to ask if you can point me some basic resources on how to use the debugger. Thank you.

```
if (s[i]-'0' >= p1[k]->info)
```

Comment: You never initialize the p1 and u1 arrays so the pointers are not guaranteed to be NULL when you test them.

Comment: What's wrong with simply using [`std::queue<char>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) for you?

Comment: @Eelke Thank you very much! I couldn't figure out that I forgot to initialize the pointers. Now it works!